# xcode 3.2.5 with iOS 4.2 crashes when deploying to device

Tags: iphone, ios

I've updated for xcode 3.2.5 and iOS 4.2 but now everytime I deploy to device (ipod touch 2nd generation with iOS 4.1 installed) it crashes the ipod and forces it to restart.

then it restarts the device and I can go open the application regularly through its icon.

but the real pain here is that everytime I deploy to the device I have to wait for it to crash, restart the device which takes ages and them open the app by clicking on its icon.

I've already changed the target sdk to be less or equal then 3.0, hence the app working after a restart as it should.

Anyone could help me with the reason for crashing the device?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a jailbreak device? If yes, anything could happen since jailbreak iOS is unstable.

Comment: yes, it is indeed @diwup, but the strangest thing is that on 4.1 it used to work without any problem, perhaps some updates on 4.2 forced jailbroken ones to fail then?

Comment: @diwup I've re-installed the ios without jailbreak this time and it worked very well, so I guess you were right, if you want to move your comment as an answer I can mark it as correct :) cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of issues with Jailbroken devices at 4.2.1; from Xcode not collecting the Symbols for 4.2.1 from the device, to issues with dylib's loading at debug time. Many debugging facilities won't run on a jailbroken device either. Check to see if you've booted in tethered mode in redsn0w, develop on a different device temporarily, or downgrade to 4.1/4.0.1.